# Error Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: reactjs

I'm a having an error in `useContext` when trying to use  in  `HomeContext` Component.

This is my Context Component

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

export const Title = createContext()

export const TitleProvider = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(props.title)

    return (
        <Title.Provider val={[name, setName]}>
            {props.children}
        </Title.Provider >
    );
}
```

The Browser indicates error here:

```
const [name, setName] = useContext(Title)
```

Here is code

```
const HeadContent = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = useContext(Title)
    console.log(name);
    return (
        <div className="headContent">

            <a className="headContent-element hover" href="#">Daily Routine</a>
            <a className="headContent-element hover" href="#">Contacts</a>
            <a className="headContent-element hover " href="#">News</a>
            <div >
                <Link to="/"><IconFont type="icon-tuichu" className="icon" /></Link>
                <Link className="headContent-element" to='/'>Log In / Sign Up</Link>

            </div>
            <DropDown />


        </div>
    );
}
export default HeadContent;
```

Comment: Where are you using the `TitleProvider` ?

Comment: I am going to use  useContext(title) in my  HeadContent